# how to stop timer with stop function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem with my code, when i press start button timer start to working
but stop timer function does not work,how to stop timer with stop function ?
please help me

here is my code:

```
def _update(self):

    """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
    self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
    self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
    self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

def _setTime(self, elap):

    """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
    hours = int(elap/3600)
    minutes = int((elap - hours*3600)/60)
    seconds = int(elap - hours*3600-minutes*60)                
    self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (hours,minutes, seconds))




def Start(self):

        """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
        if not self._running:            
          self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
          self._update()
          self._running = 1

def Run(self):                
    #self.btnstop.config(text="Start",command=self.Run)

    #if self.vs.isOpened() == False:
        #self.vs.open(0)

    """ Get frame from the video stream and show it in Tkinter """
    ok, frame = self.vs.read()  # read frame from video stream
    self.Start()
    if cv2.waitKey() == 27:
        self.Stop()
    if ok:  # frame captured without any errors
         gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert colors from BGR to RGBA



    self.current_image = Img.fromarray(frame)  # convert image for PIL
    panel = Label(self.canvas_area)  # initialize image panel
    panel.config(width=500,height=500)
    panel.grid(column=0,row=0)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.current_image)  # convert image for tkinter
    panel.imgtk = imgtk  # anchor imgtk so it does not be deleted by garbage-collector
    panel.config(image=imgtk)  # show the image

    self.after(30, self.Run)  # call the same function after 30 milliseconds
    #self._running=1    

def Stop(self):

    """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
    if   self._running:

      self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
      self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
      self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
      self._running = 0
```

Comment: What is `self.after`? How do you start and stop the timer? Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I don't know what initially calls `Run()`, but I see nothing stopping its repeated execution once that occurs — and it calls `Start()` each time it runs (which will (re)start the stopwatch).

Comment: Add a `return` right after `self.Stop()`

Comment: instead of `0`, `1` you can use `True`, `False` - it will be more readable.

Comment: if something doesn't work then first you could use `print()` to see if function is executed and what values you have in varialbes. It helps to see where is the problem. FIrst check `print(cv2.waitKey())` because it has value biggere then `27` and you have to use `cv2.waitKey() & 0xff == 27`. You should see it in all cv2's tutorials.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` only for classes but `lower_case_names` for methods, functions, variables - ie. `self.start()`, `self.stop()`, `self._set_timer()`. It helps to recognize class in code. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it so I will guess - you forgot `& 0xff` in

```
if cv2.waitKey() & 0xff == 27:
```

and it never executes `self.Stop()`

In all cv2's tutorials you should see `cv2.waitKey() & 0xff`.

---

If you use `print(cv2.waitKey())` then maybe you will see that it returns value bigger then `27` when you press `ESC`.

---

Of course it can be also other problem. I' not sure but `cv2.waitKey()` may works only when you open cv2's window because system sends keys to active window and `cv2.waitKey()` may gets key only from window created with `cv2.imshow()`

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
cv2.imshow('win', img)

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey()
    if key > -1:
        print(key)
    if key & 0xff == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you use `tkinter` to display window then you should use tkinter's methods to get key - ie `tk.bind(``, self.Stop)`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def stop(event):
    root.destroy()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<Escape>', stop)
root.focus()

root.mainloop()
```